# Subscribe inside subscribe and return an observable in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Really need help on this. I have been trying different things but its not working.

```
function1() {
  return this.apiService.get().pipe(map(data => {
    return this.function2();
  }));
  }

function2() {
   const urls = [];

   for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      urls.push(
        this.apiService
          .get('/users/?page=' + i)
          .pipe(map(data => data))
      );
    }

   forkJoin(...urls).subscribe(data => {
     data.forEach(element => {
        results = results.concat(element.results);
      });
     return results;
     })
    }


this.someService.function1().subscribe(data => {
console.log(data);
})
```

So basically, i want to print out data that i subscribe in function1(). But the results of function1() relying on function2() which another subscribe().

I do know why but just dont know how to solve it.when i run the script i alway get undefined, the reason is because the function1() could not wait the function2() to return the results.

I got stuck here. Thanks,

ANSWER: I figured out that i should not return the results in function2 as an array.

```
function2() {
   const urls = [];

   for (let i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      urls.push(
        this.apiService
          .get('/users/?page=' + i)
          .pipe(map(data => data))
      );
    }

   return forkJoin(urls);
```

and then based on the output of funtion2, i will do the rest in function1 which is the concat()....

Comment: Does function2 depends on the result from function1?

Comment: @robert yes. The data from function1() will be the augments to call function2.

Comment: @robert I have just updated my question. please take a quick look. thanks

Comment: never mind, i think i have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want `switchMap` - [Documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

Once you have the result from `function1`, you want to "switch" to waiting on `function2`

```
function1() {
    return this.apiService.get().pipe(switchMap(function1Data => {
        // Send function2 whatever data it needs
        // Example:
        return this.function2(function1Data.function2Argument).pipe(map(function2Data => {
            // Combine function1Data and function2Data as needed
            // Example:
            const result = {
                function1Property: function1Data.property,
                function2Property: function2Data.property
            };
            return result;
        }));
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have tried it but i got " Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined". The return of function2() is an array. i am not sure if that cause the issue.

Comment: I have just updated my question. Please take a quick look in function2. Thanks

Comment: Never mind. i have fixed the problem based on your commend. That helps. Thanks again.